# How to get a hidden field's value from a Dynamics email workflow?

Tags: javascript, workflow, dynamics-365

We have a functionality in our Dynamics, where:
1- Record gets created/updated.
2- Call an API.
3- Stores the API's return value in a hidden text. (created a webresource html and attached to the form)
4- Triggers an Email notification workflow via JS.

Our challenges is that #3 has a value that needs to be in #4 (the email).
We didn't create a field in the form's entity to store the API call in #3, we just wanted to use that returned value as part of the email notification.

Please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick question: 
Does your each record has unique API return value per record?
Two ways and I would personally prefer option 1

1. If yes then why not create a field in Entity itself and save that value in CRM. You can easily use that for your transaction
2. Why not create a Input parameter for Email notification workflow and pass this value in workflow, which then can be used for Email notification. (If you call an API using Js or c# code and get value back (same context of Js/C# code))

Comment: Option 1 is probably a more viable approach just coz it's the quickest and most convenient. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can create the email programmatically, in your case the plugin that calls the API can create a new email, you can then manipualte the result returned from the API. You can add new fields to the email to eventually manipulate the email farther before submitting it.

For examble add a field prj_IsThisFromTheAPI in the email, and you can double check the body before sending the emails out. At this point you will have the API returned value saved only on the body of the email, if this is sensitive you might face problems.